# Match special characters regex in Javascript (Random place)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a regex to match atleast two special characters,
for a password strength checker. I now have this in Javascript:

```
if (password.match(/([^A-Za-z0-9]{2,})/)) {
    //Add strength
}
```

But this checks that atleast two special characters that needs to be after each other. How can I make it, so that it will also check if it's not after each other?

Example:

```
_aaa!* //Match
a!a_a* //Also match
```

Comment: `/[^A-Za-z0-9].*?[^A-Za-z0-9]/` seems like it'd work. That's `[special char][zero or more anything, nongreedy][special char]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

```js
var password = 'a!a_a*';
var matches = password.match(/([^A-Za-z0-9])/g);

if (matches && matches.length >= 2) {
  console.log('Good');
} else {
  console.log('Bad');
}

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: I will use the length, with if(password.match(/([^A-Za-z0-9])/).length >= 2). Thanks ^^

Comment: Make sure not to forget the `g` global modifier.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `replace` for this:

```js
var password = 'a!a_a*';
var specialChars = password.replace(/[A-Za-z0-9]/g, '');

console.log(password, specialChars.length > 1 ? 'OK' : 'Too few special chars');
```

Answer (score 0):

`^(.*?[\*\& list all the special characters you want to allow here prefixed by \]){2,}.*$`

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/